# Android OpenGL ES 3.0: called unimplemented opengl es api

Tags: android, opengl-es

Hi I am running an application on Nexus 7, Android version 5.0. It gives me error  **called unimplemented opengl es api** . I am trying to use opengl es 3.0. I have added following to my manifest file

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000"/>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21"/>
```

Then in my make file I have

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -lGLESv3
```

I debugged the code and found error is coming in GLSurfaceView class in guardedrun function. I have custom GlSurfaceview and GLSurfaceView.Renderer. GLSurfaceView class first calls OnSurfaceCreated and it runs smoothly. It fails when it calls onSurfaceChanged function. I have called my jni draw function inside onSurfaceChanged function. So it fails in C++ code. I am not able to debug the jni code. Following is the code where I create my context

```
    private static int EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION = 0x3098;
    public EGLContext createContext(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
        Log.w(TAG, "creating OpenGL ES 3.0 context");
        checkEglError("Before eglCreateContext", egl);
        int[] attrib_list = {EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 3, EGL10.EGL_NONE };
        EGLContext context = egl.eglCreateContext(display, eglConfig, EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, attrib_list);
        checkEglError("After eglCreateContext", egl);
        return context;
    }
```

Comment: where exactly do you receive the error?

Comment: @MuertoExcobito I have updated my question. Please have a look. Can you tell me some good source to debug jni part of code. I have tried many times, but always failed to do proper setup to debug the jni part. Curretly I use cygwin to build C++ part and eclipse for java part. I can switch to Android studio or whatever you suggest

Comment: please post your code which calls eglCreateContext - likely that's where your issue lies.

Comment: @MuertoExcobito Done. please check

Comment: Is there a reason why you're creating your own context? I suspect that there's a mixup between the context you create yourself, and the context that `GLSurfaceView` already created for you.

Comment: I would assume `createContext` function posted is from a `GLSurfaceView.EGLContextFactory`? It's valid to create a context this way, and, it looks fine, so I'm not sure what the issue is. Some implementations didn't support creating an GLES 3 context, and instead exposed the functionality by using an EGL 2 context, and had the GLES 3 entrypoints in libGLESv2.so (which you could get with `eglGetProcAddress`). Not sure if this is the case with your device - I would guess not - since you'd expect Google to follow their own release guidelines.